# HP Laserjet "maintenance interval" vs "fuser life"

Tags: printing

I posted a question about the Laserjet 8100DN earlier here:
[Buying an old laser printer -- what will need to be replaced?](https://serverfault.com/questions/139043/buying-an-old-laser-printer-what-will-need-to-be-replaced)

and from doing some more research I have a **new question:**

I found the "maintence interval" -- "the interval at which you should install a maintenance kit" (which is a fuser and rollers), and it is...350,000 pages. BUT, when I look at the specs for an HP 8100 fuser, it says the fuser has a life span of 150,000 pages. What gives? – Will the fuser go bad after 150 or 350?

====

BTW I hope it's ok to ask another similar question in a new thread -- I'm just following instructions from my thread on the topic at Meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't believe their numbers. I've been using 9050dn's which they *claim* has a 300k per month duty cycle, and I've got a pile of four dead ones stacked up from running a mere 225k pages a month...They can handle it for about a 18 months. The high capacity output trays can take it for maybe 6 months. It's all on the high end as far as what they can handle...Except for maintenance kits. The kits last longer than they tell you they will: that includes fusers and rollers.

From my long experience with printers, I offer this advice: don't put in the kit until you *need* to put in the kit. When a fuser starts to go south, you get streaks, and if you pull it out and look inside it, the stuff they put on the roller will have started to de-nature. When it does this, replace it.

Likewise rollers: when the rollers are worn, they'll start jamming. If you pull one out, it'll look worn, and smooth.

If you replace the kits when they tell you to replace the kits, you're going to be giving them extra money.

Comment: Thanks, you satanic puppy, that helps.  I don't even plan to use mine more than 1000 pages per month!  But I still wonder why the discrepancy between "fuser life" at 150K and "maintenance kit life" at 350K.  Any ideas?

Comment: +1. I agree. Regardless of the stated or rated life of said parts, don't replace them until they need to be replaced. Fuser rollers should be smooth with no surtface dents, scratches, pits, flat spots, etc. Pickup\feed rollers should be slightly rough, sticky, and in some cases have a "tread", if they're shiny and smooth they need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in doing more Googling, it looks like HP's claim on the fuser is that it "might" start going bad between 200K and 250K, but that it's "rated" for 350K.  Not very helpful.

Random fuser & supply stores give all sorts of silly claims though.